# Is there any meaning to the rail lines in Bakemonogatari's "Tsubasa Cat" OP?

Tags: monogatari-series

The (NSFW, be warned) [broadcast opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuwMqYS4AIA) for the Tsubasa Cat arc of Bakemonogatari (**"Sugar Sweet Nightmare"**) features various artistic nudes with what appear to be rail tracks stretching out along the model's body, such as in this SFW sample:

[image]

The 'stations' here actually appear to correspond to various stations mostly in the Kansai area; for instance, 天見 ([Amami Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amami_Station)) is a station on the Koya Line in Osaka, and 川西 ([Kawanishi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawanishi,_Hy%C5%8Dgo)) is a small city in the same broad area.  On the other hand, a bit of digging doesn't turn up any rail lines that run between the two.

**Does anyone know if there's any meaning to the specific choice of rail stations used in this opening and their layout, or was it essentially just a mishmash of random location names?**

Comment: Apparently, three of the right-leg stations (天見, 橋本, 極楽橋) are stations 73, 77, and 86 on [the Nankai Kouya line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nankai_K%C5%8Dya_Line). Also, three of the left-leg stations (飛鳥, 吉野口, 吉野) are on the [Kintetsu Yoshino line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintetsu_Yoshino_Line). Does this mean anything? Beats me.

Comment: just as a warning about the video *"This video contains content from Sony Music Entertainment (Japan) Inc., who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds."*. i'm in Australia so it appears there is some Geoblocking being used

Answer (score 8):

## Legs

```
大正－（新今宮）　　　　　　　平野－八尾－志紀－－▽－－尺土－浮孔－坊城－飛鳥－吉野口－緞野／吉野
　　　　　　　　＞（道王寺）＜　　　　　　　　　道明寺
　　　　（？池）　　　　　　　布忍－－－高鷲－－－△－－貴志－川西－天見－橋本－極樂橋
　　  　　１　　　　　Ｘ　　　　　　２　　　　　　Ｙ　　　　　　　　　　　　　３
（　）= Full name not shown on the scene
```

These are railway lines in Osaka:

- The 1st upper-leg is [Osaka Loop Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osaka_Loop_Line): Taisho, Shin-Imamiya
- The 1st lower-leg is [? Line]: [? Station]
- The 1st interchange (X) is [Tennoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenn%C5%8Dji_Station) (accessible directly from Osaka Loop Line, Yamatoji Line)
- The 2nd upper-leg is [Yamatoji Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamatoji_Line): Hirano, Yao, Shiki
- The 2nd lower-leg is [Minami Osaka Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minami_Osaka_Line) (from Tennoji, transfer to [Osaka Abenobashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Csaka_Abenobashi_Station) in walkable distance): Nunose, Takawashi
- The 2nd interchange (Y) is [Domyoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%8Dmy%C5%8Dji_Station) (accesible from Yamatoji Line by transfering at [Kashiwara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashiwara_Station) to [Domyoji Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domyoji_Line), directly accessible from Minami Osaka Line)
- The 3rd upper-leg is Minami Osaka Line - [Yoshino Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshino_Line) (transfer at [Kashiharajingu-mae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashiharajing%C5%AB-mae_Station)): Shakudo, Ukiana, Bojo | Asuka, Yoshinoguchi, Yoshino
- The 3rd lower-leg is [Nagano Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagano_Line_(Kintetsu)) (from Minami Osaka Line, transfer at [Furuichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furuichi_Station_(Osaka))) - [Koya Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nankai_K%C5%8Dya_Line) (transfer at [Kawachinagano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawachinagano_Station)): [Kishi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishi_Station_(Osaka))<sup>1</sup>, Kawanishi | Amami, Hashimoto, Gokurakubashi*

<sup>1</sup> Uses kanji for [Kishi Station in Wakayama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishi_Station_(Wakayama)) instead.
* Uses [traditional kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai)

---

## Hands

```
（百合ヶ丘）　　　　南多魔－西府－立川－奥多魔
   　　    ＞登戸＜
　　　　　　　　　　狛江－喜多見－經堂－豪徳寺－下北澤
　　　１　　　Ｘ　　　　　　　　　　２
（　）= Full name not shown on the scene
```

These are railway lines in Kanagawa-Tokyo:

- The 1st upper-leg is [Odakyu Odawara Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odaky%C5%AB_Odawara_Line): Yurigaoka
- The interchange (X) is: [Noborito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noborito_Station) (accessible directly from Odakyu Odawara Line, Nambu Line)
- The 2nd upper-leg is [Nambu Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambu_Line) - [Ome Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cme_Line): Minami-Tama, Nishifu, Tachikawa | Okutama
- The 2nd lower-leg is Odakyu Odawara Line: Komae, Kitami, Kyodo, Gotokuji, Shimo-Kitazawa

---

## Body

```
　　　　　　　　　　高田馬場－池袋－巣鴨－上野－秋葉原－神田－＼
　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＼　　　　浅草－－－－▽－－－北千住－八潮－
三鷹－吉祥寺－新宿－－代々木－－千駄ヶ谷－－飯田橋－－御茶ノ水－－濱離宮＜　　　　　東京ガス
　　　　　　　　　＼　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　新日本橋－－△－－－錦絲町－新小岩－西船橋－東京タワー－津田沼－
　　　　　　　　　　澁谷－恵比壽－水道局－五反田－品川－有樂町／
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　｜
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　不動前　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　芝公園
　　　１　　　Ｘ　　　　　　　　　　２　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Ｙ　　　　　　　　３　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Ｚ
```

These are railway lines in Tokyo:

- The 1st leg is [Chuo Main Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%AB%C5%8D_Main_Line): Mitaka, Kichioji
- The 1st interchange (X) is: [Shinjuku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjuku_Station)
- The 2nd upper-leg is [Yamanote Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamanote_Line): Takadanobaba, Ikebukuro, Sugamo, Ueno, Akihabara, Kanda
- The 2nd middle-leg is [Chuo-Sobu Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%AB%C5%8D-S%C5%8Dbu_Line): Yoyogi, Sendagaya, Iidabashi, Ochanomizu
- The 2nd lower-leg is Yamanote Line: Shibuya*, Ebisu, **[Waterworks bureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Metropolitan_Government_Bureau_of_Waterworks)**<sup>x,2</sup>, Gotanda, Shinagawa, Yurakucho*
- The vertical-leg (2) is [Tokyo Meguro Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dky%C5%AB_Meguro_Line) (transfer at Meguro): **Waterworks bureau**<sup>x,2</sup>, Fudomae
- The 2nd interchange (Y) is: **[Hamarikyu Gardens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamarikyu_Gardens)**<sup>x,3</sup>
- The 3rd interchange (3) is: **[Tokyo Gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Gas)**<sup>x,4</sup>
- The 3rd upper-leg is [Tobu Skytree Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobu_Skytree_Line): Asakusa, Kita-Senju, Yashio
- The 3rd lower-leg is [Sobu Line (Rapid)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C5%8Dbu_Line_(Rapid)) (from Tokyo) - Chuo-Sobu Line : Shin-Nihombashi, Kinshicho*, Shin-Koiwa | Nishi-Funabashi, **[Tokyo Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Tower)**<sup>x,5</sup>, Tsudanuma
- The Z point is: **[Shiba Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiba_Park)**<sup>x</sup>

<sup>x</sup> Not a station
<sup>2</sup> Represents [Meguro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meguro_Station) on Yamanote Line. Between Ebisu and Gotanda, there's a waterworks bureau in Meguro
<sup>3</sup> Represents [Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Station) on Yamanote Line (accessible from Ochanomizu by transfering to Chuo Line)
<sup>4</sup> Represents [Higashi-Mukojima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higashi-Muk%C5%8Djima_Station) on Tobu Skytree Line and [Ryogoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ry%C5%8Dgoku_Station) on Chuo-Sobu Line. Both have Tokyo Gas near them.
<sup>5</sup> Tokyo Tower is not anywhere near the Chuo-Sobu Line
* Uses [traditional kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai)

---

## Conclusion

The railway lines are real, though they don't seem to mean anything. However, the **bolded** places on the body seem to mean something:

- Waterworks bureau near bladder
- Hamarikyu Gardens near womb
- Tokyo Gas near large intestine
- Tokyo Tower & Shiba Park are... *recreation places*

---

Reference: [a more SFW, redrawn OP by NEXIS on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBieOMHvTag)